# Are there fully-funded Software Engineering Masters degrees in USA for UK students?

Tags: masters, united-states, university

I am looking to get into software development. I have an offer for a Masters with a UK university but it an expensive course and the job market is much better in USA, paying much more generously. Hence, if it were affordable I think it might be a good idea to study there instead.

Would there be universities in the USA that are willing to provide significant funding for an international student looking to do a Masters in a course like software engineering? If it means anything, I did MSci Mathematics for my undergraduate and graduated as the top-performing student in the university.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are very unlikely to find any software engineering Masters programs in the US that offer significant (or any, really) funding, regardless of nationality.

Software engineering Masters degrees are essentially professional degrees that provide entry into a lucrative job market, much like MBAs or law degrees. Accordingly, they come with the expectation that the student will pay their own way (possibly via loans), on the expectation that they will increase their future earnings enough to make up for the up-front expenditure of their education.